# Problem updating percent of EasyPieChart by using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, json

I'm doing charts with easypiechart and when I try to update the percent value in the javascript using the code that is given by the github page, that return me this :

```
index.html:151 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'update' of undefined
    at index.html:151
```

I've tried with jquery, in vanilla js and always the same problem

That's at the end of my HTML :

```js
   <script type="text/javascript">
   $(function refreshChart() {
     setTimeout(function() {
         $('.chart').data('easyPieChart').update(40);
     }, 5000);
});
   </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like one way to get this to work is to actually instantiate the pie chart on the chart element first, and then populate it with data.

Put this bit before your update line, and it should work. This is also a space where you can control properties of the chart, such as color and size:

```
$('.chart').easyPieChart({

  });
```

So the whole block might look like:

```
$(function() {
  $('.chart').easyPieChart({

  });

  $('.chart').data('easyPieChart').update(45);
});
```

You've probably seen the documentation, although it does not look too clear from scanning it: https://github.com/rendro/easy-pie-chart

Answer (score 0):

I already initiate my charts in vanilla JS like this :

```js
new EasyPieChart(element2, {
    scale : false,
    barColor : '#80B64F',
    scaleColore : false,
    lineWidth : 6

});
```

Comment: You may be initiating the pie chart, but it needs to be attached to the chart element to be accessible through jQuery.